# how can i read the values from bootstrap "input" element, and bootstrap "drop down list" to django?

Tags: jquery, html, django

is it possible to place the curly brackes somewhere to read these values, or should i use some other method ?

```
bootstrap "input" form group :
============================
<div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Amount to invest (Example: 10000)"  />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the relevance of Bootstrap is here. Reading an input styled by Bootstrap is exactly the same as reading any other input in Django.

Comment: i thought the same, but my test showed that only surrounding html was returned but which the actual values entered (in "input" tag) nor selection values  from selection buttons - were returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to resolve the issue I used Django's **widget** feature

in form.py I placed the following markup for the input field:

> amount
>   =forms.CharField(**widget**=forms.TextInput(attrs={**'type':'number'**,**'class':'form-control
>   input-lg'**,"placeholder":"Enter Amount"}))

this allowed me to place the following the django template used:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>   

  <div class="col-md-4" style="vertical-align: top;margin:0;padding:0;">
        <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.amount }}
        </div>
  </div>                               

  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   </div><!-- /.row -->
```

this produced for me - an HTML equivalent to the HTML row

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Enter amount"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to read values from input tag in django.

in your HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control">
</div>
</form>
```

in your view.py

```
def somefunc(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
          if "amount" not in request.POST:
             amount = 0
          else:
             amount = request.POST["amount"]
        yourmodel.amount == amount
        yourmodel.save()
```

hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, the question was specifically for the Bootstrap type input field 

if you can suggest resolution for a followup question (how to combing django and dropdown toggle) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549276/bootstrap-drop-down-toggle-with-django-widget