# Bootstrap drop down toggle with django widget

Tags: django

I'd appreciate assistance in converting the following bootstrap drop down button/toggle to Django.  Meaning, I want the country that a users selected from the list -  to be returned when the form is submitted.

This is the current dropdown button definition :

```
<div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-1x" style="color:blue"></i>  United States <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
              </button> -->
  <div class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn-block" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> United states <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu columns" id="country">

         <li><a href="#">United States</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">United Kingdom </a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on list of country! I mean is it a model or predefined list you want to save in modelform.

Comment: it could be a charfield in a form (based on **forms.Form** class), 
i'm using the field to get search parameters from the user (kind of google search form)

i want a user to choose which country to search in, using the bootstrap drop down toggle.  i need the country value (name) returned to the django view.

Comment: Are you looking for autocomplete search box?

Comment: nope. a selection of one value from a list, with a click of the mouse

Answer (score 1):

I would better suggest use normal HTML form rather than django-form.
I am suitable in working with HTML form as it gives power to me to customize it to my needs.
And solution is similar to your earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443374/how-can-i-read-the-values-from-bootstrap-input-element-and-bootstrap-drop-do/38549644?noredirect=1#comment64494073_38549644)
So In your HTML template

```
<select class="form-control" name="country>
     <option value="India">India></option>
     <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
     ....
</select>
```

in your views.py

```
def someview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        country_name = request.POST['country']
    
    somemodel.objectname = countryname
    somemodel.save()
```

Remember to use name attribute in your form tag and request the same in view. It works for all html form tags.